# Difference in speed if website and database on same/different server

Tags: database

Are there any difference in database connection speed (initial DB connection request, queries, etc.) at all if:

**A.** Website and database are on the same server. Basically host is `localhost`.

**B.** Website is on `Server I` and database is on `Server II`. Website will access database via remote IP address.

Actual speed test will really help.

Comment: Go measure yourself ^^.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the connection between the Servers. A connection within localhost is normally faster because you're staying on the same system and no request or connection has to go through the network.

Comment: Thank you pDiller! I think `localhost` connection is faster too but are there any actual speed test on any website regarding this. I tried searching but can't seem to find any result. Our website is moving from `localhost` to remote access so this concerns me.

Comment: You can test this with some Tools like Wireshark which logs the connectiontime and request. I don´t know if it logs the connection on localhost but normally it should.

Comment: Er, I checked out Wireshark at their website. First impression: I think it is for Network Administrator--it looks scary. Will try to install it when I have time.